# $L^1([0,1])$ closed unit ball is not weakly compact

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, weak-topology

So I would like to prove this result by constructing a sequence of functions  $u_n$ in $L^1([0,1])$, such that $\|u_n\|_{L^1}\leq 1$ for all $n$, but this subsequence does not have a convergent subsequence.

My idea was to take an approximation to the identity, say, $u_n = n\mathbf{1}_{[0,1/n]}$. Taking any continuous function on $\phi$ on $[0,1]$, ($\phi$ is also $L^{\infty}$ as a result), defines a linear functional on $L^1$:
$$
f(u_n) = \int_0^1 u_n\phi \mathrm{d}\mu
$$
And taking the limit to infinity, we see that $f(u_n) = \phi(0)$. Here is where my argument needs work: "This means that $u_n$ converges weakly to the Delta function, but this is not an element of $L^1$". How can I clarify this? Do I have to use the sequence:
$$
\int_0^1 u_n\phi \mathrm{d}\mu
$$
as a sequence in the dual of $C[0,1]$ and show then that $f_n(\phi) \xrightarrow{w*} \phi(0)$ ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Good question. Note that for weak convergence, you need convergence of the dual pairing of the sequence with *all* elements of the dual. In other words, you would need to show the claim for all functions $\phi \in L^\infty$, not just for continuous $\phi$.

Comment: And in fact, you may explicitly construct a function $\phi \in L^\infty$ such that $\int u_n \phi\,d\mu$ fails to converge.

Comment: Or do you mean the topology on $L^1$ inherited from the weak-* topology on $C([0,1])^*$?  Maybe you should precisely define the topology you mean.

Comment: If the latter, then you need to prove the statement "there does not exist $u \in L^1$ such that $\int u \phi\,d\mu = \phi(0)$ for all $\phi \in C([0,1])$".  For that, consider a sequence like $\phi_n(t) = (1-t)^n$.  Use dominated convergence to show that $\int u \phi_n \,d\mu \to 0$ for any $u$, yet $\phi_n(0)=1$.

Comment: @NateEldredge what would that $L^\infty$ function be? I assume if I construct such a function then we would not have weak convergence.

Comment: Please give the exact definition of "weak convergence" that you are using, before we take this any further.

Comment: A sequence $x_n$ in a Banach space $X$ converges in the weak topology to $x \in X$ if for any linear functional $\varphi$ we have that $\varphi(x_n) \to \varphi(x)$. In the case of $L^1$, we can identify $(L^1)*$ with $L^\infty$, and every linear functional on $L^1([0,1])$ can be written as $\varphi(u_n) = \langle u_n ,\phi \rangle = \int_0^1 u_n(x)\phi(x) \mathrm{d}x$ . Thus, we must have $\int_0^1 u_n(x)\phi(x) \mathrm{d}x \to \int_0^1 u(x)\phi(x) \mathrm{d}x$  for any $\phi \in L^{\infty}$ if $u$ is the weak limit of $u_n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is an answer that is inspired by Nate Eldrege's comments.

Let $u_n$ be an approximation to the identity. Clearly, $\|u_n\|_{L^1} \leq 1$ for all $n$. Assume now that $u_n$ has a weak subsequential limit, i.e $u_{n_k} \rightharpoonup u$ in $L^1$. Then, for any $L^\infty[0,1]$ function $\phi$ we must have:
$$
\int_0^1 u_{n_k}\phi \to \int_0^1 u \phi
$$
Moreover, we know by that $u_n$ has the property that:
$$
\int_0^1 u_n \phi \to \phi(0)
$$
for continuous $\phi$. Hence:
$$
\int_0^1 u_{n_k} \phi \to \phi(0) = \int_0^1 u\phi
$$
or every $\phi$ continuous. Now, we will show that no such $u$ in $L^1$ exists. Take the sequence $\phi_n = (1-x)^n$ on $[0,1]$ . Then, we see that:
$$
\int_0^1 u\phi_n =\phi_n(0) = 1
$$
for all $n$. It follows then that:
$$
\int_0^1 u\phi_n =\phi_n(0) \to  1
$$
By the dominated convergence theorem (bounding $u \phi_n$ by $u$, which we assume is $L^1$), we have that:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 u\phi_{n} = \int_0^1 u\lim_{n \to \infty} \phi_n
$$
$\phi_n$ converges pointwise to the function $1$ at $0$, and $0$ elsewhere. Hence, we have:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 u\phi_{n} = \int_0^1 u\lim_{n \to \infty} \phi_n = 0
$$
But we showed above that the limit is $1$. So this cannot happen.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an argument that shows that your sequence works:

Let $u_{n_k}$ be any subsequence of $u_n$. Assume that the weak limit of $u_{n_k}$ exists, denoted by $u$. Then, as $u_{n_k} \to 0$ almost everywhere, we have $u\equiv 0$, because weak limits and almost sure limits coincide (this can be seen by noting that both weak convergence and almost sure convergence cause convergence in probability of a subsequence). But if we let $\phi \equiv 1$, we find

$$ 1 = \int_{0}^{1} u_{n_k} \phi ~ \mathrm{d}\mu \to  \int_{0}^{1} u \phi ~ \mathrm{d}\mu = 0, $$

a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would you prove the weak and almost everywhere limits coincide without the language of probability theory?

Comment: Make the replacements "almost sure" -> "almost everywhere", and "in probability" -> "in measure".

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that a subsequence $(u_{n_k})_{k\geqslant 1}$ converges weakly in $\mathbb L^1$ to some $u$. For all fixed $\delta$ and all Borel subset $B$ of $[0,1]$ included in $(\delta,1)$, using the definition of weak convergence with the linear functional associated to the indicator function of $B$, we derive that $\int_B u=0$ hence for all $N$, $u(x)=0$ for almost every $x\in (1/N,1)$. Therefore, the only possible limit for $(u_{n_k})_{k\geqslant 1}$ is $u=0$. But this does not work, for example using the functional $L\colon f\mapsto \int f$: $L(u_{n_k})=1$ but $L(u)=0$.